# COM: vendor-supplied TLB file

Tags: ruby, winapi, com, win32ole, typelib

I have this vendor-supplied TLB file, which I've used to generate a Ruby proxy class. However, the TLB in question describes 6 interfaces and 3 classes:

> AcdAutomationServer (I)
>
> AcdAutomationServerClass (C)
>
> AcdEvent (I)
>
> AcdEventClass (C)
>
> AcdObject (I)
>
> AcdObjectClass (C)
>
> IAcdAutomationServer (I)
>
> IAcdEvent (I)
>
> IAcdObject (I)

But running the OLEGEN tool of Ruby's 1.8.6 win32ole library class (located in \doc\ruby\ruby-1.8.6\sample\win32ole) generates a Ruby proxy class containing:

> module IAcdAutomationServer (...)
>
> class Ccs_Application (...)
>
> module IAcdEvent (...)
>
> module AcdEvent (...)
>
> module IAcdObject (...)
>
> module AcdObject (...)

I need to instantiate objects of types other than Ccs_Application! With only modules, how can I execute, for example, AcdEvent's method Connect that has to be run on AcdEvent objects?

Anyone with Ruby COM experience? Thanks in advance!

Comment: May it be that the classes not imported into Ruby are simply marked as non-creatable?

Comment: @sharptooth -- I think that's pretty likely, you should add it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, with help from Masaki Suketa, is shown [here](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2079). This is only possible in Ruby 1.9's WIN32OLE module, since it requires instantiating WIN32OLE::VARIANT objects.